# Долгая обработка базы MySQL

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Доброго всем времени суток господа

```
// очень ресурсо требовательный запрос, и даже не из за *
$zapros = mysql_query(SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE ... LIMIT 50);

// тут смотрим есть ли записи
if(mysql_num_rows($zapros)>0){
    // прошло столько то времени, сделано это и это

    // производим некоторые манипуляции с данными // ~ 6-7 сек
    // удаляем записи которые нашли в $zapros

    // тут скрипт, который перезагружает страницу каждую 1/1000 секунду    
}
else{
    echo "ура, все сделано";
}
```

Конструкцию использую для определенной обработки данных, когда нужно из таблицы кое что выковырять, обработать и отдать, а саму таблицу грохнуть. Как видно, пока записи в таблице есть - скрипт перезагружает страницу, и идут запросы/очистка_записей, как записи кончаются - скрипт перезагрузки страницы не запускается.

Немного поясню. Скрипт перезагрузки страницы срабатывает не каждую 1/1000 секунду, а время обработки данных + 1/1000 секунды = так как и должно быть. И это хорошо

Вопрос:
 - Можно ли оптимизировать обработку данных так, что бы не было скрипта перезагружаещего страницу?

Comment: Длительные операции через cron.
Либо перегружать страницу, других вариантов нет.

Comment: я ни с какой стороны не веб-программист, но почему бы не обновлять данные на странице через ajax или что-нибудь сравнимое?

Comment: @VladD прав - используем AJAX, получаем результат и обновляем соответственно страничку.

Единственное - без конкретной задачи трудно что-то конкретное сказать, но может быть и правда стоит запускать задачу в кроне, результат писать в файл, а AJAXом обращаться к скрипту, который этот файл обрабатывает?

Убиваем сразу несколько зайцев - страница быстро обрабатывается, длительные операции выполняются в фоне и не грузят веб-сервер, можно получить результат работы скрипта разными клиентами.

Comment: @BOPOH: отделение обработки данных (запрос) от представления результата (обновление страницы) вообще очень хорошая идея.

Comment: @VladD, думал напишете мне что то циклическое на php. Завтра попробую по шаманить с AJAX. Если можно засунь свой коммент в ответы, я ему сделаю акцепт, т.к. не люблю не принятые ответы, а этот наиболее близкий к правильному

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Похоже на реализацию worker'а — рабочего процесса, который по маленьким порциям обрабатывает большой массив данных.

Я бы делал это без связки с веб-интерфейсом и перезагрузкой страниц: по расписанию, из командной строки. Тогда появляется возможность использовать конфиг и сборку php отличную от публичной для сайта, оптимизированную под задачу - без лишних модулей, с другими лимитами по времени исполнения. И появляется возможность масштабировать выполнение, распараллелив его может, на несколько серверов, читающих единую БД.

Ответ же на ваш вопрос "можно ли .. без перезагрузки страниц" — можно, ajax'ом бомбить.

Answer (score 1):

Оптимизировать обработку данных? Конечно можно. Но это требует хотя бы видеть реализацию этой обработки.

Но ваш вопрос задан с тегом **javascript**. И если вы его используете, то тут можно придумать такое решение. Запускайте ваш скрипт обработки **AJAX**-запросом и не отдавайте результат обработки до тех пор, пока она не будет выполнена. Получится техника, напоминающая [long polling](http://javascript.ru/ajax/comet/long-poll).

Вы, однако, можете упереться в ограничение вашего веб-сервера по максимальному времени обработки запроса. Если вы имеете возможность настраивать сервер, эту настройку можно отрегулировать. В любом случае такой механизм будет прозрачнее постоянных перезагрузок.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы сделал таблицу `table` в памяти (`memory table`) - что ускорит процесс на порядок
`ajax` добавлять не стал, т.к. это только прибавит нагрузку в браузере - что скажется на ещё более долгой обработке скрипта.

з.ы. Опишите задачу подробнее, не понятно что за данные, и зачем так делать. Кажется реализация в корне неправильная, поэтому и городить костыли приходится....