# Автоматическая посылка ajax запроса при определенном значении в success

Tags: ajax, php, javascript

Доброго всем времени суток господа

Иду в правильную сторону, после неправильной [темы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/213268/php-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B-mysql). Есть страница, которая аджаксом посылает данные 2й странице. 2я, ест-но возвращает результат.

```
// page1.php - первая страница
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <title>jQuery.ajax</title>
  <script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#buttonUpload").click(function(){
       $.ajax({
         url: "page2.php",
         type: "POST",
         cache:true,
         data: {data:$("#textUpload").val()},
         success: function(data){   
           $("#dataUpload").html(data);
         }
       });
     });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="hidden" id="textUpload" value="<? if(!isset($_SESSION["num"])){echo "1000000";}else{$_SESSION["num"];} ?>" />
  <a style="#" id="buttonUpload">Погнали!</a>
  <div id="dataUpload"></div>
</body>
</html>

    // page2.php - вторая страница
    session_start();
    header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");
    if($_SERVER["HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH"] == "XMLHttpRequest"){
        if(!isset($_SESSION["num"])){
            $_SESSION["num"]=$_POST["data"];
        }
        else{
            $_SESSION["num"]=$_SESSION["num"]-1;
        }
    }
    echo $_SESSION["num"];
```

Собственно, нажатием на ссылку, отправляется миллион на страницу 2. Принимаем данные - получаем число на 1 меньше. И так продолжается, сколько раз мы нажмем.

Вопрос: Можно ли, при получении данных, скажем более 500'000 - автоматически обновлять div=dataUpload (как сейчас) и отправлять POST запрос снова, а при возвращаемом 500'000 или менее - обновить требуемый div своей переменной? т.е. получиться, что страница будет обновляться с 1'000'000 до 500'000, и пошлет 500'000 запросов второй странице.

p.s. в работающем виде можно посмотреть [тут](http://v-kv.com/ajax/page1.php), прошу не считать за рекламу, т.к. хостинг тестовый. И прошу там ничего не ломать ))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#buttonUpload").click(function() {
    var callee = arguments.callee;

    $.ajax({
        url: "page2.php",
        type: "POST",
        cache:true,
        data: {
            data:$("#textUpload").text()
        }
    })
    .done(function(data) {
        if (parseInt(data) > 500000) {
            $("#dataUpload").text(data);
            callee();
        } else {
            $("#dataUpload").text('the end');
        }
    })
    .fail(function(){
        $("#dataUpload").text('some fail');
    });

});
  });
```

Comment: Оно самое! Огромное спасибо. Буду не только пользоваться, но и пересматривать и вникать, что там к чему.

Answer (score 2):

```
function ajax_request(url, send_data) {
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: "POST",
      cache:true,
      data: {data:send_data},
      success: function(data){  
        onSuccess(data); 
        if(data > 500000) {
          $("#dataUpload").html(data);
          ajax_request(url, send_data)
        } else {
          // Обновление с Вашей переменной
          $("#dataUpload").html("Менее 500 000");
        }
      }
    });
  }

  $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#buttonUpload").click(function(){
       ajax_request("page2.php", $("#textUpload").val());
     });
  });
```

Comment: В качестве второго решения попробую разобрать.